# Preinstall packages for a nodejs Docker Image according to package.json

Tags: docker, dockerfile, node.js

I would like to prepare a Docker image for a nodejs project. The developers use package.json to list their node module dependencies. I would like to prepare the Docker image (as base on the Dockerfile), with most of the node_modules already installed "globally" on the image.

Is there a best practice to prepare nodejs images?

Answer (score 1):

Depend of life cycle of you app, because Node libraries and dependences change or end life to obsolet, so if you app constant change version to deploy, you can use [docker tag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/tag/) for describe version or time when it build image, is a good practice, so Dockerfile shall copy package.json, and too look when you need change image source OS, by example change ubuntu linux to alpine , many dependences or how to install "npm" and dependences for node, a example:

```
  FROM alpine:3.8

# Update
RUN apk add --update nodejs nodejs-npm

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /src/package.json

RUN cd /src; npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /src

EXPOSE 5000
CMD ["node","src/index.js"]
```

well , hope it help you

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this is a production `Dockerfile`, the boilerplate configuration for a Nodejs type of application would look like this:

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
```

or like this:

```
FROM node:alpine
WORKDIR "/app"
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

and if you involve Nginx, you may additionally have a couple of lines that would look something like this:

```
FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

So now you have a couple of answers with a few variations of how you could write out the production ready `Dockerfile`.